# How to create toggle button with label without duplicating code?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, controls, toggle

I need to have a text near a toggle button which says on/off relatively.

I achieved that by simply having a stack panel with a toggle button and label next to it and then in the code behind I simply use the Checked/Unchecked events to change the content of the label.
The problem is that I have many toggle buttons and my method duplicates code (for each toggle button I have a label, and 2 functions).
Is there a more efficient way to do it?

```
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
 <ToggleButton Name="First" Checked="First_Checked" Unchecked="First_Unchecked"/>
     <Label Name="FirstLB" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
       </StackPanel>

     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ToggleButton Name="Second" Checked="Second_Checked" Unchecked="Second_Unchecked"/>
                        <Label Name="SecondLB" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
       </StackPanel>


    private void First_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FirstLB.Content = "Off";
    }

    private void Second_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SecondLB.Content = "Off";

    }

    private void First_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FirstLB.Content = "On";
    }

    private void Second_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SecondLB.Content = "On";

    }
```

Comment: Can you give me some code, please? How will I access the label of each toggle button?

Comment: Besides that, do you really need the Label? Why don't you set the ToggleButton's own Content?

Comment: And yes, I do need the label- The text should appear next to the button

Comment: Have you considered using CheckBoxes?

Comment: Unfortunately I need a toggle button.

Comment: Can you explain what did you mean in the first comment?

Comment: You might either move the Label (which should actually be a TextBlock) into a ContentTemplate used as the ToggleButton's Template, or perhaps simpler, create a UserControl. How are these ToggleButtons supposed to be used? Will they just be bound to a boolean property in a view model?

Comment: Yes, It is only on or off

Answer (score 1):

You may create a simple UserControl with an `IsChecked` property like that of the ToggleButton class:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Off"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                                     Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="On"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

With this code behind:

```
public partial class OnOffButton : UserControl
{
    public OnOffButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty =
        ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty.AddOwner(
            typeof(OnOffButton),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public bool? IsChecked
    {
        get { return (bool?)GetValue(IsCheckedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

You can use it like a ToggleButton:

```
<local:OnOffButton IsChecked="{Binding SomeViewModelProperty}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to a UserControl that does not go too much into styling would be a nested ToggleButton and TextBlock in the ControlTemplate for a ToggleButton:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton" x:Key="OnOffToggleButtonTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="label" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Off"/>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="label" Property="Text" Value="On"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Which would be used like this:

```
<ToggleButton Template="{StaticResource OnOffToggleButtonTemplate}"
              IsChecked="{Binding SomeViewModelProperty}" />
```

Comment: It is good solution but too messy... I posted what I actually needed

Comment: Well, instead of *messy* I'd call it *reusable*.

Comment: I would hesitate to call this "correct", since there is a nested ToggleButton, but it is simple. The probably best approach would be a templated RadioButton, but that would involve a lot more XAML.

Answer (score 0):

Well, simple as it sounds I created a dictionary
Dictionary Btns;

added all the buttons and labels.

and then created one function for checked and one for unchecked:

```
 private void Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Btns[(ToggleButton)sender].Content = "on;
        }

        private void UnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Btns[(ToggleButton)sender].Content = "off";
        }
```